# Why does `SET NAMES utf8` change the behaviour of `REPLACE(uuid(),...)` calls?

Tags: mysql, replace, mysql-workbench, uuid

While investigating an issue with a failing migration I found out the following strange behaviour. Using `SET NAMES utf8` on my client session changes the behaviour of `REPLACE(uuid(),'','')` calls.

```
mysql> select replace(uuid(),'','') from mysql.user;
+--------------------------------------+
| replace(uuid(),'','')                |
+--------------------------------------+
| 4b483d57-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| 4b483d57-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| 4b483d57-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select replace(uuid(),'','') from mysql.user;
+--------------------------------------+
| replace(uuid(),'','')                |
+--------------------------------------+
| 539c0b5c-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| 539c0b79-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| 539c0b7f-ecdc-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

As you can see the generated UUID's are unique only *after* setting `NAMES` to `utf8`. The way I found out about `SET NAMES utf8` was passing the query through MySQL Workbench.

I would greatly appreciate if someone here can explain how  character sets (`NAMES`) influence the output of `REPLACE(UUID(), ...)` calls. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: adding a snippet to prove that the problem 1) is not with `UUID()` generating non-unique values and 2) relates to `utf8mb4` charset

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select uuid, replace(uuid,'','') from ( select uuid() as uuid from mysql.user) tmp;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| uuid                                 | replace(uuid,'','')                  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| e41d2fe4-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e41d2dc2-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| e41d3042-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e41d2dc2-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| e41d309c-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e41d2dc2-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select uuid, replace(uuid,'','') from ( select uuid() as uuid from mysql.user) tmp;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| uuid                                 | replace(uuid,'','')                  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| e9059092-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e9059117-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| e90591a1-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e905923e-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| e9059380-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | e90593e1-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set names utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select uuid, replace(uuid,'','') from ( select uuid() as uuid from mysql.user) tmp;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| uuid                                 | replace(uuid,'','')                  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ef564f32-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | ef564d0c-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| ef564fa4-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | ef564d0c-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
| ef565019-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 | ef564d0c-ed70-11e8-844f-0242ac120002 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Update 2**: Adding `EXPLAIN` queries below to trace the actual SQL code as suggested by @qbolec. That reveals that the use of `CONVERT(... using ...)` is the culprit for the non-unique UUIDs. I still do not exactly understand why as this is not the behaviour I expect from `CONVERT()` func.

```
mysql> set names utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select replace(uuid(),'','') from mysql.user;\W
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 276     | NULL |    7 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1003): /* select#1 */ select replace(convert(uuid() using utf8mb4),'','') AS `replace(uuid(),'','')` from `mysql`.`user`
Show warnings enabled.

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select replace(uuid(),'','') from mysql.user;\W
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 276     | NULL |    7 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1003): /* select#1 */ select replace(uuid(),'','') AS `replace(uuid(),'','')` from `mysql`.`user`
Show warnings enabled.
```

Comment: Its normal the uuid varies on the first block. Maybe, the problem are because the first query has been executed too fast (uuid is time based). Check wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for more information about uuid composition.

Comment: Have you tried to set back the connection/client charset to the value it had originally and what comes out then?

Comment: @MikeLischke I just tried that with the same effect. Original charset is utf8mb4. I updated my question to include the test commands I used.

Comment: You can try `EXPLAIN <your query>` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS\G` to see what your query looks like after optimizer applies it's magic. I have a suspicion, that optimizer changes the query into non-equivalent form in which `uuid()` is called multiple times per single row. My belief is that it should never do that, but perhaps it only does so for certain code-pages/configurations. IMHO it is worth reporting as a https://bugs.mysql.com